# Arrow Functions as Methods: Value of this

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) presents the following two examples of arrow functions

**Example 1**

```
var adder = {
  base: 1,

  addThruCall: function(a) {
    var f = v => v + this.base;
    var b = {
      base: 2
    };

    return f.call(b, a);
  }
};

console.log(adder.addThruCall(1)); // 2
```

**Example 2**

```
'use strict';
var obj = {
  i: 10,
  b: () => console.log(this.i, this),
  c: function() {
    console.log(this.i, this);
  }
}
obj.b(); // prints undefined, Window {...} (or the global object)
obj.c(); // prints 10, Object {...}
```

**Question**

- `this.base` in Example 1 points to `adder.base`
- `this.i` from property `b` in Example 2 resolves to `undefined`

If arrow functions do not have a `this` value, should not `this.base` also resolve to `undefined`?

Comment: In the first example `this` inside the arrow function is lexically scoped. That's what it means "not having a `this`".

Comment: *"arrow functions do not have a this value"* - this is not entirely correct, arrow functions simply treat `this` like any other variable without special meaning (lexical binding) while traditional functions have this special exception for `this`.

Comment: @le_m A lexical binding, yes, but the name "`this`" only resolves because they do not have their own `this` value (which would be chosen over the parent scope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions have a "this", it's whatever "this" is in the current scope when you define them.

In you second example, in arrow function `b()`, since you have no particular parent scope defining "this", "this" is pointing to "Window" (in a browser context)

Also in your second example, in named function `c()`, `function()...` introduces a scope, and this is `undefined` by default.

So what you see is completely expected. However, as you can see, "this" is complicated to master, so good code style suggest to avoid it if you can. In this case, you may want to use a closure.

Interesting read about this in this other question: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Thanks for all the solid answers, hard to pick one. After having understood a bit more, I just wanted to add the following for the benefit of future visitors: 1) In functions, `this` refers to the object the function is executing in. Exceptions to this rule include: Closures/nested functions (scope is lost, `this` refers to global object); arrow functions (`this` refers to enclosing context's `this` value); when otherwise specified with `bind`, `call`, `apply`; when function is called in global context (`this` refers to global object).

Comment: Continuation of above comment: In Example 1, the arrow function's `this` value, is the `this` value of the enclosing function (as arrow functions do not have their own `this` value). The normal rule applies to the enclosing function (`this` refers to the adder object, as adder called the `addThruCall` function). In Example 2, also being an arrow function, `this` again refer to the `this` value of the enclosing context. Here though, the enclosing context is the global context (as there is no outer function). Thus, `this` in the arrow function equals the global object.

Answer (score 2):

In example 1, the arrow function `f` is created inside of the function `addThruCall` inside of `adder`. That means `this` inside of `f` will point to addThruCall's `this`, which is `adder`.

In example 2, the arrow function `b` is not inside of any normal function, so its `this` doesn't point anywhere.

It's not that arrow functions don't have a `this` value, it's that arrow functions will not change the `this` value from where they are created.

Comment: They really do not have a `this` value. It resolves to the parent scope's `this` value, and when that changes the "arrow function's `this`" will reflect this change. It's not stored when they are created.